# how to load another html on expiry of the html?

Tags: android, html, caching, header

I was trying to make a sample HTML page and I have set the

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="expires" CONTENT="Wed, 08 Aug 2011 11:00 PDT">
```

I want to load updated HTML on expiry of the HTML.
Note : The server is local to the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the user's browser to load a different page after a certain amount of time.  If so, you don't want to use "expires", you want to use "refresh" instead.  "Expires" is for giving hints to the browser about what is safe to cache, and has nothing to do with causing the page to reload.

This will cause the page to load example.com after 10 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://example.com/">
```